# Odds of Two People having one DOB and another two people having a different DOB in a Group

Tags: probability, birthday

So the odds of in a room of 14, two people sharing a DOB, and another two people sharing another DOB is 4.97%.

However, I cannot figure out how to get to 4.97%. I calculated it being 1.9% by doing the following:

```
•the number of ways to choose the two duplicated birthdays: (365/2) 
•the number of ways to assign the earlier birthday to two people, and the later birthday to two other people: (14/2)(12/2)         
 •the number of ways to assign 10 out of the remaining 363 days to the rest of the people: 363!/353!
```

Dividing this product by the number of ways to distribute birthdays without restrictions yields the final probability of 1.9%.

Where is the 4.97% coming from?

Comment: Does the problem require exactly two matches of exactly two people and then 10 people each on their own (different) day; or can we also count other cases with more than that minimal amount of matching?

Comment: It is exactly two matches of exactly two people. The other ten have their own birthday.

Comment: I added it there too. I am new to stack exchange so I wasn't sure of the protocol